# RequestTrackingAuthorization on MacOS/MacCatalyst

Tags: macos, tracking, mac-catalyst, apptrackingtransparency

I have an app for `iOS`, where request for tracking shows dialog. But when I run it on `MacOS(MacCatalyst)` no dialog is showed.

I tried to create new project for testing but it also not working.
I call in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: {
    (status) in print(status)             
    switch status {
        case.authorized:
        break
    
        case .notDetermined:
        break
        
        case .restricted: 
        break
        
        case .denied:
        break
        
        @unknown default:
        break
        }
})
```